# ¿Cómo centrar un botón que tiene texto en un div?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `div` que tiene un 33.33% de ancho y adentro hay un botón con texto. El problema está en que no puedo centrar el botón dentro del `div`, teniendo en cuenta que también tiene texto y que sea responsivo.

Éste es el código:

```css
div {
  width: 33.33%;
}

button {

}
```

```html
<div class="w-33">
  <button>
    upgrade ahora
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola José Eduardo, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Ésta es una pregunta bastante básica (lo cual no es malo) que ya se ha realizado antes en el sitio. Podrías indicar ¿qué has intentado? ¿o qué has investigado? Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que completes el [tour]

Answer (score 5):

Lo mejor es crear un `div` dentro del `div.w-33` y centrarlo.

```css
div.w-33 {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.center {
  text-align: center;
}

button {}
```

```html
<div class="w-33">
  <div class="center">
    <button>
      upgrade ahora
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede solucionar de varias formas, te dejo a continuación 2 de las que considero más utiles.

**1ª Forma:**

Se aplica un margen por la izquierda del 50% (Medida que se aplica sobre el contenedor), después se translada el botón hacia la izquierda el 50% de si mismo (como si quitasemos la mitad de su logitud), es decir:

[image: Margen de 50% por la izquierda del botón.]
*Margen de 50% por la izquierda del botón.*
[image: Translación hacia la izquierda del botón el 50% de si mismo.]
*Translación hacia la izquierda del botón el 50% de si mismo.*

**2ª Forma:**

Con flexbox, se calcula el centro del contenedor y del elemento, y se translada el elemento de tal forma que ambos centros coincidan (todo ello de forma transparente al desarrollador), simplemente utilizando las propiedades adecuadas.

**Código:**

Aquí dejo el código de ambos métodos.

```css
div.contenedor {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: tomato
}

button.centrado {
  width: 110px; /* Para que no se rompa en dos líneas, y lo translade tal cual. */
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* OTRA FORMA (flex):
div.contenedor {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <button class="centrado">Boton centrado</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button{ transform: translateX(330%); }
```

- El **`330%`** es un valor relativo que me funcionó
- Pero en algunos casos es **`50%`** ó **`-50%`**

Depende de tu código.

Answer (score -1):

Hola puedes intentar con esto

```
div{
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```

Comment: El div tiene una medida de 33%. El boton tiene texto y le he puesto un tamaño de 1.7rem. Quiero que el botón este centrado, al igual que el texto, pero cuando intento que sea responsivo, el texto sale del botón.

Comment: tendrias que usar una media query @media (max-width: 600px) {
  button{
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo codigo, no siempre sirven. Siempre se pide que expliques un poco que hace esto. mira por favor [answer]